# Excel 2016 Looking up earliest date that is later than the lookup date, while also exact matching an ID Index(match) or Vlookup

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I'm trying to do matching between two spreadsheets using an Id and a Date field.  I need an exact match on the ID, but the closest date that is greater than or equal to a date in the other table.

Specifically I'm trying to create the equivalent of the following SQL through a form of index(match) or Vlookup.

```
 Select min(b.date)
 from a
 join b
   on a.id = b.id
   and b.date >= a.date
```

If I had access to Access I'd use that, but unfortunately its not an option, so its something I have to do in excel directly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the second table sorted at all?

Comment: I can sort b as needed, right now it is sorted by b.date in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two formula will do what you want:

Array MIN(IF()):

```
=MIN(IF(($B$2:$B$15>=E2)*($A$2:$A$15=E1),$B$2:$B$15))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` Around the formula.

The Second uses AGGREGATE and gets entered normally:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$15/(($A$2:$A$15=E1)*($B$2:$B$15>=E2)),1)
```

[image]

---

***NOTE***

Neither formula require the data to be sorted.